# Registering service with provider() and factory() - $http not found in the latter

Tags: angularjs

I'm creating a new module with some services. And I register the service like the following:

```
myModule.provider("surveySrv", ["$http", function ($http) {
  var httpSrv = $http;
  return {
    $get: function () {
      return {
        getall: function () {
          return httpSrv.get("/api/survey/all");
        },
        remove: function (survey) {
          // ...
        }
      };
    }
  };
}]);
```

And I get an error Failed to instantiate module ilgServices due to:
*Unknown provider: $http*

Can't figure out why.
But if I register it with the factory method it works:

```
myModule.factory("surveySrv", ["$http", function ($http) {
    return {
      getall: function () {
      return $http.get("/api/survey/all");
    },
    remove: function (survey) {
      //return $http.get()
    }
  };
}])
```

I got this explanation on the GitHub:

You can only inject things into the  $get  property of a provider. The  $get  property is what gets injected into your controllers/directives/services. The main body of the provider is primarily for config blocks to alter the behaviour of the provider.

But have a question - how do I "inject things into the $get property"?

Answer (score 1):

The `module#provider` is invoked during the configuration phase when only providers are allowed to be injected.

You can inject the services into the $get function like so:

```
myModule.provider("surveySrv", function () {     
  return {
    $get: ["$http", function ($http) {
      return {
        getall: function () {
          return $http.get("/api/survey/all");
        },
        remove: function (survey) {
          // ...
        }
      };
    }]
  };
});
```